# Can Scion of the Ur Dragon's ability fizzle a spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want to know if [Scion of The Ur-Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bScion%20of%20The%20Ur-Dragon%5d)'s activated ability can fizzle a kill spell or the like by becoming a copy of a card?

Does the ability make him another permanent as a response to any spell that would kill him essentially removing him as a valid target?

Comment: Not an answer, but worth mentioning since I've seen this sort of thing confuse a lot of people: Scion's ability isn't a mana ability. A mana ability is one that generates mana (with some restrictions), not one that costs mana.

Comment: @MichaelSnook Indeed, and I've edited the question to fix that issue.

Comment: @MichaelSnook Ah thanks for clearing that up. I can see why its misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't reliably counter the spell.**

Changing into a copy of something else doesn't make the Scion a different object. However, if the dragon it becomes is an illegal target (for example, due to having hexproof, or any other attributes that the target relies on) then that would work.

Comment: So if someone cast Murder for example, the target would still remain after scion changed?

Comment: @ThunderToes: That is precisely what it means. As Samthere stated, the permanent doesn't become a new object (which it would if it changed zones, for example).

Comment: @ThunderToes Yes, the object that was named Scion is still the same object, and still the target, even though the name and characteristics changed. Murder would still work. However, if the spell was Plummet, you could turn the Scion into Canopy Dragon and the spell would fizzle, since the target doesn't have flying.

Comment: Rightio, that clears this up then. Its kinda a good thing that its this way or Scion would be infinitely more OP than it already is haha.